# only allow numbers and fullstop (period) in textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, keycode

I know that the following code blocks the usser from ussing spaces in a textbox however how do i allow the user to only use numbbers and a fulstop (so i can add values like 1.5)

```
    Private Sub Textbox4_keyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox4.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
        TextBox4.Clear()
        MsgBox("Invalid character. No spaces Permited...")

    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

From a usability point of view, testing for valid input in the `KeyDown` event isn’t good. For example, what happens when the user wants to paste text into your text box?

Furthmore, the user can still paste invalid input using the TextBox’ context menu, your code won’t notice this.

*You should allow all input*, and then test for validity when the user *leaves* the text box. VB has an extra event for this, which is fired whenever the text box loses focus: `Validating`. Use this event (and *only* this event) to test for valid input.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach for this might be to look for the "allowed" characters, if not one of them, show the error message.

Comment: i just googeld cant find anything on allowed characters could you mabey point me the right way?

Answer (score 0):

In last 20years of writing code I always use the following rationale for TextBoxes Check Characters.
First you have to create a separate Class which you may call it (for your convenience) Char_Validation.
Inside to this Class you’ll put a Function which returns Boolean as follows .

```
Public Class Char_Validation
    Public Const Gr As String = "Greek"
    Public Const En As String = "English"
    Public Const Num As String = "Numbers"
    Public Const FullGr As String = "Full Greek"
    Public Const FullEn As String = "Full English"
    Public Const EnN As String = "English with Numbers"
    Public Const GrN As String = "Greek with Numbers"

    Public Shared Function ValidateChar(ByVal AsciiChar As String, ByVal CharTable As String, ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) As Boolean
        Dim ConvChar As Integer = CUInt(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(AsciiChar))
        Dim ConvCharW As Integer = CUInt(Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW(AsciiChar))

        ValidateChar = False

        Select Case CharTable
            Case En
                Select Case ConvChar
                    Case 65 To 126, 145 To 150, 8, 32 To 47, 58 To 64, 128, 130
                        ValidateChar = True
                End Select
            Case EnN
                Select Case ConvChar
                    Case 48 To 57, 65 To 126, 8, 32, 45
                        ValidateChar = True
                End Select
.
.
.
.
.
            Case Num
                Select Case ConvChar
                    Case 44 To 57, 92, 8
                        ValidateChar = True
                End Select
        End Select

    End Function
End Class
```

At your Class in Form you will use the TextBox_KeyPress on which you’ll use the following code.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        ErrorProvider1.Clear()
        ErrorLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
    Select Case Char_Validation.ValidateChar(e.KeyChar, Char_Validation.Num, sender, e)
            Case True
            Case False
                ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, "Wrong Character Only Numbers")
                Beep()
    e.KeyChar = ""
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Thus you will prohibit the user to place characters out of your decision.
I hope that will cover you from now.

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me on : firefox, IE 8, chrome, Safari and iphone.

function dotplaced(myfield){
    if(myfield.indexOf(".")===-1){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function NumbersOnly(myfield, e) {
    var key;
    var keychar;

```
if (window.event) {
    key = window.event.keyCode;
}
else if (e) {
    key = e.which;
}
else {
    return true;
}

keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

// control keys
if ((key == null) || (key == 0) || (key == 8) ||
(key == 9) || (key == 13) || (key == 27)) {
    return true;
}
// numbers
else if ((("0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1)) {
    return true;
}
// decimal point jump
else if (!dotplaced(myfield.value) && (keychar == ".")) {
    //myfield.form.elements[dec].focus();        
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

}